# Navigate into HTML LU LI with AJAX

Tags: ajax

I've an HTML FILE like :

```
<div id="mydiv">
   <ul id="myul">
      <li id="1"> LI 1 </li>
      <li id="2"> LI 2 </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

In an other HTML file, I try to make a filter for the object into this list of item, with AJAX.

My script like that :

$(document).ready( function() {

```
    $('#filter_search').keyup( function(touche){

    $field = $(this);

    if($field.val().length > 1) {

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open ('GET','data/mylist.html');

        var length = 30;

        xhr.addEventListener ('readystatechange',function(){

            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {

                var result = xhr.responseText;

                (...)
```

But it's not a good solution for browse the elements of my HTML.
Have you got a solution ?

Comment: as you are using jquery .. use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ or possibly what you really want to do is replace stuff in the DOM? Then use http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Thank you for you comment but if I use the jQuery.get I've a return of all my HTML in text. What I want is to browse the **li** values.

Comment: You should explain better what you need to achieve - if you're goal is to match some input of the user `$('#filter_search').val()` to something inside the __data/mylist.html__ I, personally, would use JSON, use https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ and then iterate over those entries.

Comment: I've a lis in my FILE1 with an include (FILE2.html). FILE2.html is my data list like the first example of this post. I've an input in my FILE1 and I need to have a dynamic filter on my input. I know to do that with Json but in this case I can't use a Json.

Answer (score 0):

From the little you tell us of what you want to do and under what restrictions (e.g. no JSON) I'd say you need to jQuery.load the FILE2 DOM into a hidden FILE1 DOM element to then iterate over the contents. You could even use an IFRAME variable to keep it off the FILE1 DOM .. if you like.

Comment: Okay so if I understand what you say, if I do that :  `var test = [];
test = $( "#my_div" ).load( "FILE2.html li");
console.log (test);` I can find my object ?

Comment: More like `$("#test_div").load("FILE2.html");console.log($("#test_div").find("li"));`.